# Xtify xid returns always null in a vodafone smart II registration

Tags: android, xtify

I had implemented the sample of Xtify sdk in 3 phones, it works in 2 but there is one that it doesn't work (the XtifySDK.getXidKey() returns always null no matter the number of times the instruction XtifySDK.start is called.

I've checked every steps of my implementation and it's accorded with the tutorial. I've sent an email to xtify support and they confirmed that my implementation is correct.

I'm using a Vodafone Smart II with android 2.3.7. Has anyone else experienced this issue with this specific phone?

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't a gmail account configured in this particular phone (it's a test phone not mine), so I configured it, clean and deploy the project again and the issue became solved.